# Error in nflfastR::calculate_expected_points(data) %>% dplyr::select(season, : could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r, dataframe, generics, runtime-error, pair-programming

which reason to prone this error anybody can helpout

Data analysis for NFL FAST R project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call dplyr's library.

```
library(dplyr)
```